# Sending Test Email in Workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I am editing a workflow (that I did not create) and inside the email that it sends, there is this link that I cannot click on. So I want to have the workflow send me the email so I can click on it through my email client to see where it leads to. Is it possible to send an email without having to run the workflow? There is an if statement that it has to go through in order to send the email and I don't want to go through the trouble to initiate it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to make a workflow generate an e-mail without running the workflow through the branch that creates the e-mail...

This is one reason why debugging workflows isn't very easy.